# HTML <div>, puzzle like top-border

Tags: html

I was working on a webpage. I have a div, I'd like its top border to look like a puzzle piece, something like this:-

[image: A container having a puzzle piece like top edge]

I am not sure how to do it. Could someone guide me pls?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code so far? If so, posting it would allow us to help you better.

Comment: I'll help you out a bit. Two divs: one rectangular and one circular. Both have the same horizontal alignment. The vertical alignment is a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a :before element using CSS to pull this off?  You could have a single DIV with a white background then do something like this:

```
div {
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
}

div:before {
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 50%; <- You'll need to play with this value a bit more
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```